# Create temporary directory for Junit test in static method for theory

Tags: java, junit4, junit-theory

I have some code which writes files to a directory of my choosing.  I currently have a test which makes use of JUnit Theories to run this code with many different directories.  It looks similar to:

```
@DataPoints
public static File[] produceListOfDirs() {
    return new File[] {
        new File("some directory path here")
    }
}

@Theory
public void myTest(File f) {
    ... run my code being tested with f ...
}
```

The problem is that I want to have the directories that get created (and the files that get created within them) be removed upon test completion (whether by success or failure).

Ideally this would just be to use a `@Rule` to specify a temporary directory & use it:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@DataPoints
public static File[] produceListOfDirs() {
    return new File[] {
        new File(testFolder.getRoot())
    }
}

@Theory
public void myTest(File f) {
    ... run my code being tested with f ...
}
```

But of course the problem here is that @DataPoints can only annotate static methods, and the TemporaryFolder rule must not be static.

Any elegant solutions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `@BeforeClass` annotation on a method to setup the required directory or files as fields of the test class.  The `@AfterClass` annotation can then be used to tear them down.

```
private static File directory;
@BeforeClass 
public static void setup() {
      directory = new File("/path/to/file");
      if(!directory.exists()){
          directory.mkdir();
      }
}

@AfterClass 
public static void teardown() {
      if(directory.exists()){
          FileUtils.deleteDirectory(directory); //apache-commons-io
      }
}
```

**@BeforeClass**

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup
>   (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the
>   independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization.
>   Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes
>   it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class. The
>   @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those the
>   current class.
>   [Documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html)

**@AfterClass**

> If you allocate expensive external resources in a BeforeClass method
>   you need to release them after all the tests in the class have run.
>   Annotating a public static void method with @AfterClass causes that
>   method to be run after all the tests in the class have been run. All
>   @AfterClass methods are guaranteed to run even if a BeforeClass method
>   throws an exception. The @AfterClass methods declared in superclasses
>   will be run after those of the current class.
>   [Documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html)

Comment: @AdamParkin Would this fit your situation?

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm.  Though there is a typo in the `@After` method, the directory should be deleted if it exists (the `!` negation in front of the `exists()` check shouldn't be there).  Only things I did differently was I created the directory name randomly via `UUID`, put it into the system-wide temp directory and enclosed the `deleteDirectory()` call in a try/catch.  The gist: https://gist.github.com/pzelnip/6080964

Comment: @AdamParkin Awesome stuff! I was hoping to hear back from you about how this went.  Nice Question!